# SalesForce Scheduled apex jobs stuck at queued

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have 2 apex classes that I have scheduled to run. One of them is scheduled to run at 1:00 am every morning. The other is a garbage class I created to troubleshoot why the first one wasn't running. Basically what is happening is the jobs are stuck at "Queued" in the job monitor. It stays this way forever. Below is the code for the test class. I can't post the real one for security reasons, but this one is doing the exact same thing. As a side note they both run fine scheduled in a sandbox. They also both run fine in both production and sandbox if run with anonymous apex.

```
global class CheqTest implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {           
        string one = 'Im making a note here';
        StillAlive();   
    }
    global void StillAlive    (){
        string one = 'Im making a note here';
        one = 'Huge success!';
        one = 'Its hard to overstate my satisfaction';
        one = 'Aperture Science';
        one = 'We do what we must because we can';
        one = 'For the good of all of us';           
        one = 'Except the ones who are dead';
        one = 'But theres point crying over every mistake';
        one = 'We just keep on trying till we run out of cake';
        one = 'And the science gets done and we make a neat gun';
        one = 'For the people who are still alive';
        one = 'Im not even angry';
        one = 'Im being so sincere right now';
        one = 'Even though you broke my heart and killed me';
        one = 'And tore me to pieces';
        one = 'And threw every piece into a fire';
        one = 'As they burned it hurt because I was so happy for you!';
        one = 'Now these points of data make a beautiful line';
        one = 'And were out of beta were releasing on time';
        one = 'Im making a note here';
        one = 'Huge success!';
        one = 'Its hard to overstate my satisfaction';
        one = 'Aperture Science';
        one = 'We do what we must because we can';
        one = 'For the good of all of us';           
        one = 'Except the ones who are dead';
        one = 'But theres point crying over every mistake';
        one = 'We just keep on trying till we run out of cake';
        one = 'And the science gets done and we make a neat gun';
        one = 'For the people who are still alive';
        one = 'Im not even angry';
        one = 'Im being so sincere right now';
        one = 'Even though you broke my heart and killed me';
        one = 'And tore me to pieces';
        one = 'And threw every piece into a fire';
        one = 'As they burned it hurt because I was so happy for you!';
        one = 'Now these points of data make a beautiful line';
        one = 'And were out of beta were releasing on time';
        System.Debug('This was a triumph');
        }
}
```

If any one has any ideas as to why they won't run help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can ask Salesforce questions directly on salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is an issue that can only be remedied by Salesforce support. There is clearly an issue with your org or underlying instance.